# Created new account instead of just assigning OpenID

Tags: support, openid, duplicate-user

...and I've therefore lost my stats and posts/questions.
I'm sure the stats of my old profile aren't amazing to many people here but I would prefer keeping them.

I was in the middle of writing an email to SO and decided to visit metaSO to see if this has happened before. Turns out there are people who have done the same.

I remember reading one of the questions where a moderator recommended flagging the question, so I have done so.

[Old, unregistered profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220314/helloworld)

Current, registered user: /users/220294/helloworld
*(New account doesn't allow posting 2 links)*

Thanks in advance!

*EDIT: Forgot to add second link*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please email the address at the bottom of every web page. Specific per-user requests like this aren't useful on meta.

Comment: Apologies.
email sent to: team@stackoverflow.com